# Nokia home application (Nokia E63)

Tags: widget, nokia

I have a nokia E63 and I want to develop a very simple application available in the main menu (desktop? home? dashboard? main-menu? can't find a consistent name for this...) that simply allows users to change between 5 modes of my application.

How to develop this particular kind of "widget" using c++/qt (or java)?

[image: (This model)]

Comment: Do you means `Active Standby Plugins` ? They are not on public API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app is a Qt app. way to go would be, use [Wrt homescreen widget](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Homescreen_widget_guidelines) and combine it with your Qt app as explained [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?218254-Combining-a-WRT-Homescreen-Widget-and-QT-Fullscreen-App) .